# Session.Message is showing two buttons with same text in WiX

Tags: wix, custom-action

I am trying to show a message during custom action failure but the dialog is showing two buttons with the same text `Close`, like the image below. Is there a way to change the text to something more meaningful?

[image]

Here is the code:

```cs
Record recordErrorMsg = new Record();
recordErrorMsg.FormatString = "Custom action error";
session.Message(
                InstallMessage.Error |
               (InstallMessage)MessageIcon.Error |
               (InstallMessage)MessageButtons.RetryCancel,
               recordErrorMsg);
```

Comment: The `FormatString` in the picture is different from the one in the code excerpt, but I know it doesn't affect the problem.